# Empty feed in Facebook page plugin (embedded feed widget)

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm integrating a Facebook Page feed using the Facebook Page Plugin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Although it's working fine for almost all pages, I'm having an issue with one Facebook page. The page plugin is displayed but the feed is empty, no post at all.

The page I'm trying to embed:
https://www.facebook.com/ConnectHearingAsheboro/

The web page where the widget is setup:
https://www.connecthearing.com/hearing-clinics/nc/asheboro/

Publications on the page are correctly displayed when on Facebook site, even when being logged out.

Does somebody have an idea of why would that occur ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is not a bug, it's a feature

Facebook support answered me here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1109206649216632/

The Facebook page I'm using in the widget is sharing posts from its parent Facebook page. The Facebook page widget doesn't include the parent page posts, it's just the way it's been built.

It's a dead end.